# Forcing colorbar ticks at min/max values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, contourf

I am plotting using the `contourf` function from `matplotlib` and would like to add a colorbar, I've noticed that sometimes the ticks don't go the max/min values.

Is there a clean way to force it to set ticks at these values?

**Note:** Checking the `max` and `min` of `z` shows that the colorbar represents values from approx -1 to 1, therefor I would expect this ot be reflected such that one can see the range from the colobar, in addition to some ticks in between.

Plot and code demonstrating what I am talking about:

[image: Heatmap with colorbar]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data to plot.
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(7), np.arange(10))
z = np.sin(0.5 * x) * np.cos(0.52 * y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=25)
ax.grid(c="k", ls="-", alpha=0.3)
fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax)

fig.savefig("example.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way seems to be to give explicit levels to `contourf`.  If no explicit levels are given, `contourf` seems to choose its own, depending on the minimum and maximum value in the data, and also tries to find "nice looking" numbers.  After that, ticks get set to a subset of these numbers, such that a tick always coincides with a real level.  (If you use `colorbar(..., ticks=...)` those ticks will not necessarily coincide with the levels.)

As the sine and cosine don't reach `-1` and `1` exact in the given example, they are not part of the range.

The following code shows how the ticks depend on the chosen levels. With `np.linspace(-1, 1, 24)` the levels aren't nice round numbers, but matplotlib still chooses a subset to show.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(7), np.arange(10))
z = np.sin(0.5 * x) * np.cos(0.52 * y)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 3))
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    numcontours = 25 if ax == ax1 else 24
    cs = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=np.linspace(-1, 1, numcontours))
    ax.grid(c="k", ls="-", alpha=0.3)
    fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'{numcontours} levels from -1 to 1')
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing contourf plots]

Comment: When I said -1 and 1, the max was actually 0.997.... so I just rounded it to 1.

Comment: My remark was about trying to make sense of what matplotlib does behind the scenes. It was not meant as a remark upon your remark ...

Comment: Ah okay I misunderstood, so the reason the colorbar doens't extend to the min/max values is because they're not "nice"?

Comment: It seems to have a hard time deciding what is "nice" and what the best way is to find close enough "nice" values.